# Import Product Information from MSSQL to MySQL (or Magento)

Tags: product, database, import, mssql

I have Products Information stored in MSSQL database and i want this Product Information into Magento or MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used magento Soap API V2 and installed mssql driver to import products to magento (mysql). I had imported using following steps

**Step 1**:- Installed MSSQL Driver on my server. and connected to the Mssql database with query

**Step 2**:- Fetched the products data from the product table at MSSQL table. Using simple select query and looped the records and used in step 3.

**Step 3**:- Used magento Soap api v2 for creating products at Magento

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://yourmagentohost.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$session = $client->login('yourapiusername','yourapipassword');

$client->catalogProductCreate($session, 'simple', $set, $sku, array(
    'categories' => array(2),
    'websites' => array(1),
    'name' => $row['name'],
    'description' => $row['description'],
    'short_description' => $row['short_description'],
    'weight' => $row['weight'],
    'status' => '2',
    'visibility' => '4',
    'price' => $row['price'],
    'tax_class_id' => 1,
    'meta_title' => '',
    'meta_keyword' => '',
    'meta_description' => '',
    'additional_attributes' => array(
        'single_data' => array(
            array('key'=>'brand', 'value'=>$row['brand']),
            array('key'=>'model', 'value'=>$row['model']),
        ),
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Our erp system is running on ms sql server.

On daily base we export all sku for the magento online shop with a sql script based on a erp sales price list.

The export contains the sku number, short description, long description, prices and stock level.

In addition we added some online shop related settings in the erp system e.g. catalog, increments, discontinued, replaced-by, update-selling, cross-selling. This settings control the sku behaviour in the shop.

The csv data is transfered with winscp to the linux based magento server.

The import is managed by MAGMI (free of charge) triggered by crontab.

```
http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page
```

Please be aware to make a safe magmi configuration.

The magmi importer tries to match existing pictures (same name es sku.jpg) on the magento server.

We use 2 store views and import language related information with a second magmi import.

We use this solution for about 5000 sku, the process is running very stable. The sku are automatically added or updated. The insert / update is very fast, the indexing takes some time. For the 5000 parts the daily update is finished after 1 hour (including magento full backup before with 10 minutes).

Comment: erp (enterprise ressource planning) is the software to run the company (sales, purchase, production, finance, service). Magmi is an open source magento mass importer program. You can run it with a webinterface or script based. Enclosed the link `http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/` and a weblink with some inforamtion `https://www.phpro.be/news/magmi-magento-mass-importer`.